# Windows Registry DWORD modification

Tags: python-3.x, windows, registry

Looking for some assistance on a script I am working on.

The goal of the script is to automatically change the REG_DWORD subkey for "tftpserver1", this is for the application Cisco IP communicator.

The REG_DWORD takes an IP address in HEX or decimal. A slight hiccup is that the value for the IP address needs to be reversed. EX) 10.11.12.13, needs to be reversed to 13.12.11.10 and then converted to HEX or decimal and updated in the REG_DWORD.

The problem I see using the example IP address 10.11.12.13 - after converting to binary and reversing, the value of the decimal back to an IP address shows as 31.21.11.1, NOT the 31.21.11.10 as desired.

Testing with a separate variable as a string: variable testip. The example IP address 11.12.13.14 - after converting to binary and reversing, the value of the decimal back to an IP address shows as 41.31.21.11, which IS desired.

I'm unsure why the ending zero is being stripped. This is a problem because if it were entered into the registry

As shown in the screenshot if the decimal value of the iptoint variable is configured in the registry, the IP set for the CIPC(Cisco IP Communicator) is 1.12.13.14 NOT 10.12.13.14, If I were to MANUALLY configure the value of the iptoint2 variable, it would be 11.12.13.14 which would be correct.

[CIPC TFTP Server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seXxS.png)

```
#Modules imported
import configparser
import winreg
import ipaddress

def regkey(): 
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                                                                          # Variable for configparser as config
    config.read(r'<ACTUAL DIRECTORY REDRACTED>IP_VARS.ini')          #REMOVED DIRECTORY FOR THIS POST                                               # Variable to read .INI file
    tftp1 = config['IP_VAR_1']['tftp_server1']                                                                                    # Variable to pull 'tftp_server' IP from .INI
    testip = "11.12.13.14"                                                                                                        # Variable for second test IP as a string
    iptoint =  int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(tftp1[::-1]))                                                                            # Variable to take tftp1 as string turn into decimal(integer)
    iptoint2 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(testip[::-1]))                                                                           # Variable to take testip as string, turn into decimal(integer)

    tshoot = ipaddress.IPv4Address(iptoint)
    tshoot2 = ipaddress.IPv4Address(iptoint2)

    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:                                                         # Connect to registry as hkey
        with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, r"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Cisco Systems, Inc.\Communicator", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as sub_key: # Open hkey for CIPC as sub_key
            current_key_value,current_key_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(sub_key, "TftpServer1")                                      # Show current sub_key value



        print("This is the Current Decimal Value of the Tftpserver1 DWORD:" + "\t" + f"{current_key_value}")
        print("This is the Type of the DWORD:" +  "\t" + f"{current_key_type}")
        print()
        print("The below value is the selected TFTP server IP, converted to decimal and reversed.")
        print()
        print(iptoint)
        print("This is testip variable converted to decimal and reversed")
        print()
        print(iptoint2)
        print()
        print(tshoot)
        print(tshoot2)
```

Result

```
This is the Current Decimal Value of the Tftpserver1 DWORD: 689902859
This is the Type of the DWORD:  4

The below value is the selected TFTP server IP, converted to decimal and reversed.

521472769
This is testip variable converted to decimal and reversed

689902859

31.21.11.1
41.31.21.11

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As a disclaimer, I am EXTREMELY new to coding. Feel free to talk to me like i'm 5 years old. Any assistance would be appreciated. This is my first time posting for scripting help, so please let me know if I need to explain anything else regarding my code/issue.

Answer (score 0):

End up fixing the problem like So:

```
import configparser
    def reverse(ip):
        if len(ip) <= 1:
            return ip
        return '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                                                                          # Variable for configparser as config
    config.read(r'C:\Users\Gerni\Desktop\JarvisGerni Script\IP_VARS.ini')                                                         # Variable to read .INI file
    tftp1 = config['IP_VAR_1']['tftp_server1']                                                                                    # Variable to pull 'tftp_server' IP from .INI
    
    print(reverse(tftp1))
```

Result:

```
  13.12.11.10
```